# Multiple context root for single war deployment jboss-EAP-6.1

Tags: java, jboss, war, jboss-eap-6, contextroot

In my `Jboss-EAP-6.1` I have deployed a `.war` called `'myRealWebApp.war'`
I can access my app with this url - http://mywebsite.com/myRealWebApp

I want to configure my webapp `'myRealWebApp'` with multiple context root. 
I mean if I access

```
http://mywebsite.com/appA
http://mywebsite.com/appB
http://mywebsite.com/appC
```

those 3 contexts `'appA'`,`'appB'`,`'appC'` points to `myRealWebApp.war` (One single war deployed)

Is there anyway I can archive this?

Thanks.

Edit:
**Solution found:**
I added this code to my `standalone-full.xml`

```
   <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:1.4" default-virtual-server="default-host" native="false">
        <connector name="http" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="http" socket-binding="http"/>
        <virtual-server name="default-host" enable-welcome-root="true">
            <alias name="localhost"/>
            <alias name="example.com"/>
            <rewrite name="rule-1" pattern="^/appA(.*)$" substitution="/myRealWebApp$1" flags="L"/>
            <rewrite name="rule-2" pattern="^/appB(.*)$" substitution="/myRealWebApp$1" flags="L"/>
            <rewrite name="rule-3" pattern="^/appC(.*)$" substitution="/myRealWebApp$1" flags="L"/>
        </virtual-server>
    </subsystem>
```

The key is the ***flags="L"***

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by configuring an http server in front of the jboss (like an Apache server) and using redirect rulea to translate all the other urls to the one you have configured your application with.
It might be that jboss also has a apache module for integration ,but the basic principle remains.
Usually it is the recommendec way not to expose directly a jboss or other app server in production, but using http server in front of it ( you can serve static content from http server, you can balance requests, etc)

Comment: Nginx is an alternative to Apache

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the Solution shared by OP, this is what I did to achieve multiple context for the single deployed.

Configured one context root in ***app/WEB-INF/jboss-web.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web>
    <context-root>appA</context-root>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>10</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</jboss-web>
```

Added `rewrite` rule in ***jboss-eap/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml***:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:2.2" default-virtual-server="default-host" native="false">
    <connector name="http" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="http" socket-binding="http"/>
    <virtual-server name="default-host" enable-welcome-root="true">
        <alias name="localhost"/>
        <alias name="example.com"/>
        <rewrite name="rule-1" pattern="^/appB(.*)$" substitution="/appA$1" flags="L"/>
        <rewrite name="rule-2" pattern="^/appC(.*)$" substitution="/appA$1" flags="L"/>
    </virtual-server>
</subsystem>
```

Comment: I did the same configuration in Standalone.xml but it is not working is there anything else I need to do ?